# R package tabnet, how to change the loss to balanced accuracy?

Tags: r, neural-network, loss-function

In the [tabnet package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tabnet/index.html), I want the loss to be the balanced accuracy for multi-class classification. Similar to `yardstick::bal_accuracy_vec()`. How can I do that?

I do know how to compute a balanced accuracy but I don't know how to create a function that would fit in the tabnet framework. So basically, any help in how to customize the loss in tabnet is welcome.

Example:

```
library(tabnet)
library(recipes)

data("attrition", package = "modeldata")
ids <- sample(nrow(attrition), 256)

rec <-
  recipe(Attrition + JobSatisfaction ~ ., data = attrition[ids, ]) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric(),-all_outcomes())

attrition_fit <-
  tabnet_fit(rec,
             data = attrition[ids, ],
             epochs = 2,
             valid_split = 0.2,
             loss = yardstick::bal_accuracy_vec
             )
```

gives the error:`Error in x != y :  comparison (2) is possible only for atomic and list types`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: yardstick metrics are used in the tidymodels tune package to search for the best hyperparameters, e.g. in `tune_grid()`. For model *training* in tabnet you'd need to use the options available in `tabnet_config()`. [Tabnet for R](https://mlverse.github.io/tabnet/index.html) ports [dreamquark-ai/tabnet](https://dreamquark-ai.github.io/tabnet/generated_docs/README.html#default-eval-metric) which does support balanced_accuracy, so maybe worth an ask on [Github](https://github.com/mlverse/tabnet) if it's available in the R version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the same thing on the tabnet guthub repo, I got the answer :

Custom loss is supported as a function in {tabnet}

The good news is that you have an example in here : https://github.com/mlverse/tabnet/blob/3d3ce9925cc12a13adf9e7b2c2c9ebd57c7f3d5e/tests/testthat/test-hardhat_parameters.R#L211-L229

The bad news is that you must rely on {torch} loss, and you can not use {yardstick} metric as a loss. The reason is that the function must be differentiable to drive the gradient in the right direction...

There is plenty of loss functions in {torch}, all ending with _loss. If one is missing, you can also build yours as a torch module like entmax and sparsemax in https://github.com/mlverse/tabnet/blob/main/R/sparsemax.R

Hope it helps,